# How to get the context of a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), and I'm trying to debug a weird error where jQuery Tools Overlay breaks all of the `.live` handlers on the page, except for ones with the context (second argument of jQuery select `$(selector, context)`) specified. So my specific question is how to find where this context is when it's not specified.

Comment: The code is more a part of the backstory than the question, so I didn't feel pasting it was terribly relevant. In any case, I solved the issue. I rewrote `Math.random` as a [joke](http://xkcd.com/221/), which apparently broke the interaction between jQuery Tools and `.live()`. I removed it, and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-specified context [defaults to `document`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

> By default, selectors perform their
>   searches within the DOM starting at
>   the document root. However, an
>   alternate context can be given for the
>   search by using the optional second
>   parameter to the $() function.